# What would break if control-reaches-end-of-body were to return nullopt?

Tags: c++, c++17

C++14 gave us automatic return type deduction, and C++17 has an `optional<T>` type template (or type constructor, if you will). Now, true, `optional` lives within the standard library, not the language itself, but - why not use it as  return value from a non-void function when control reaches the end of the body? I would think that:

```
optional<int> foo(int x)
{
    if (x > 0) return 2 * x;
}
```

should be perfectly valid and compilable syntax for a partial function, returning `optional<int>`.

Now, I know this is a bit of a crazy idea. My question is not whether you like it or not, but rather - suppose everyone on the committee really liked it for some strange reason. What would it break / conflict with?

**Note:** Of course if you specify a non-optional return value this can't work, but that doesn't count as breakage.

Comment: All paths must return the same type or co-variant with return type deduction.

Comment: @NathanOliver : I think I understand what you mean, but probably not well enough, since I don't see how that would conflict with my suggestion. I'm not fluent enough in standardese :-)

Comment: An `optional<int>` and an `int` are different types.  The function has to return the same type on all paths.  Its like how the true and false parts of operator ? need to be the same.

Comment: Obvious conflict: It would turn undefined behavior (as in your case) into well-defined behavior. Code, that used to be wrong would be propagated into the realms of valid code all of a sudden.

Comment: @NathanOliver: So, no implicit conversion. I could say "let's have that too, for optionals, or at least for this special case", but - ok, I guess one crazy suggestion at a time. Let me tweak my example to be less radical.

Comment: @IInspectable: That's not breakage per se. I mean, when you add syntax like structured bindings or lambdas or type deduction you also take something which was not valid - wouldn't compile - and may it valid.

Comment: This just adds an exception to the rules where none currently exists (okay, except `main()`, but that's already a special function). The point of allowing control to reach the end of a function with a return value is that sometimes the programmer knows more than the type system can express, and by eliding what are otherwise pointless return statements you can get a faster/smaller/better/whatever program.

Comment: To close voters: this is **not** subjective. If einpoklum were to write a proposal for WG21, this would require an objective answer.

Comment: I never claimed, that this were "breakage". I called it a conflict, and it is.

Comment: @IInspectable Obviously if it's conflict, it's meaningless conflict that nobody cares about, because otherwise it would stop anyone from adding anything to the language.

Comment: Even if nothing break, it'd feel particularly strange to insert an implicit `return nullopt` at the end of some functions because they return optional<T> (which is an interesting type, but one among many others), and not `return null` at the end of a function returning T*.

Comment: @RémiBonnet: What's the problem with [feeling particularly strange](http://s3.birthmoviesdeath.com/images/made/doctor_strange_large_1280_720_81_s_c1.jpg)? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Think of functions that end with `abort();` or a custom function that has the same effect. If the compiler cannot statically prove functions never reach the closing `}`, this would force the compiler to generate dead code, and is therefore in conflict with one of the principles of C++, namely the *zero overhead principle*: what you don't use, you don't pay for.

Comment: Where do you assume such overhead would exist? In the function itself, or in the caller?

Comment: @MSalters In the function itself. It's no overhead in execution time, but it is an overhead in code size.

Comment: Actually, if the compiler can inline the code, the proposed implicit return path might affect the execution time as well. Optimizers these days are very good at deducing impossible values, such as `optional<int>.has_value()==false` and using that to eliminate branches

Comment: @MSalters Good point, I hadn't thought of that. It only applies when the function has a return type `optional<T>` yet always returns a `T`, but there can be good reasons for that, such as compatibility with an existing interface.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. `abort()` is a `[[noreturn]]` function, are you sure that's the example you wanted to give?  I was talking about functions which _do_ reach the closing `}`, and _do_ need to return something; why would I want to prove they don't? Right now, the functions I described simply don't compile. If you adopt my proposal, it would be equivalent to concluding the body with return `nullopt`; how does this break zero-overhead?

Comment: @einpoklum : Right now it's UB ([stmt.return]/2); a compiler may issue some diagnostic, but it certainly isn't required. (Not detracting from your point, just nitpicking.)

Comment: @einpoklum `T f() { abort(); /**/ }` is valid for all `T` that can act as a return type, even though the function doesn't return anything. "Right now, the functions I described simply don't compile." is wrong. The functions *do* compile. Your proposal would force the compiler to insert code at the `/**/` that is never called and is completely useless, unless the compiler can manage to prove that it is useless, and proving that is non-trivial. If you're saying that it's trivial because of `[[noreturn]]`, then pretend I wrote `error()` instead, where `error()` is a user-defined function.

Comment: hvd: If you wrote `error()`, which doesn't return in fact but the compiler can't prove it, it's in UB territory. Why would you expect optimization of undefined-behavior code, for unmarked `[[noreturn]]` functions (which themselves seem odd to focus on.)

Comment: @einpoklum Nonsense. It may be UB for a non-`void`-returning function to reach the closing `}`, but that only applies if the code actually reaches the closing `}`. By your logic, `int f() { if (1) return 1; }` is UB, because the compiler might not optimise away the `if` statement. In fact, it's well-defined, because it doesn't matter whether the compiler optimises it away: the behaviour is only undefined if the closing `}` is reached, and it won't be reached no matter what optimisation level you choose.

Answer (score 3):

Special casing `std::optional` is ridiculous here.  Users should be able to write their own first-class equivalent to `std::optional`.

Which means falling off the end of a function needs to involve using some kind of magic to figure out what the implicit return value should be.

The easiest magic is that falling-off-the-end is equivalent to `return {};`  In the case of `optional`, this is `nullopt`.  If I read my standardese correctly, for `int` this is `0`, and this matches the behavior of falling-off-the-end-of-`main`.

There are downsides.  First, suppose you have a function:

```
int foo(bool condition) {
  if (condition) return 7;
  custom_abort(); // does not return, but not marked up with `[[noreturn]]`
}
```

This would cause the compiler to write a `return {};` after `custom_abort();` if the compiler cannot prove that `abort` doesn't return.  This has a cost (in binary size at the least).  Currently, the compiler is free to exclude any work required to return from `foo` after `abort()` and *assume* `abort()` will not return.

It is true that no valid programs will behave differently with this change, but what was previously undefined behavior becomes defined, and that can have costs.

We could approach this in a slightly different way:

```
int foo(bool condition) {
  if (condition) return 7;
  custom_abort();
  this cannot be reached;
}
```

where we add in an explicit "this location cannot be reached" to C++.

Once added, we could then issue warnings for code paths that do not return, and in a later standard enforce the rule that all code paths must either assert they cannot be reached, or must return.

After such a transformation of the language was in place for a standard cycle or two, then implicit `return {};` would be harmless, except for people who skipped over the return cannot happen phase of standardization.

Comment: You're making a different, much broader suggestion than mine. Now, you object to the special-casing of `std::optional` - after all, it's just a library class as far as the compiler is concerned, right? Well, I would say that not really. `optional` and `variant` are on the way to being considered - by developers if not by compilers at this point - as practically a structural part of the language. And I do only care about partial functions, so I don't see enough of a motivation for your suggestion. It's not such a bad idea of course, just not what I asked about.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm objecting for a practical reason.  There are decisions made in designing optional (and variant etc).  These decisions *may not be optimal*.  So a `maybe` type is written that has different tradeoffs than `optional`; as an example, maybe it supports out-of-gamut values for `T` which allow zero space cost optional types.  Now, if you elevate optional with built-in language support in a way that a different `maybe` type cannot match, you make `maybe` relatively worse.  Thus such a feature *should not be locked to `std::optional`*.

Answer (score 2):

Up to now, it is full Undefined Behavior. That means no valid existing code contains this construct. Adding well-defined behavior will therefore break no valid code. As for code that was broken, that may or may not be broken if your proposal would be accepted, but that's almost never a concern for WG21.

The main concern would be how it would interact with other language features. I don't see a conflict with `constexpr`; falling off the end of a `constexpr` function would give an empty `constexpr optional<T>`. The `[[noreturn]]` attribute obviously makes no sense. The `[[nodiscard]]` attribute affects the caller, not the implementation. Exceptions are not affected either. So on the whole, the proposal seems to stand on its own.

In a proposal to WG21, it might be worth suggesting a less radical alternative: make plain `return;` a valid alternative for `return optional<T>{};`

Comment: But why? A bunch of special-casing to avoid typing `std::nullopt`?

Comment: @GManNickG: Fair question, but a WG21 proposal needs multiple sections. I wrote the "why not?" section, but you indeed still need to add the "why?" section.

Comment: @GManNickG: It's not to avoid typing. It's a language-evolutionary feature towards better expressibility of partial functions. But I don't have a solid motivation fleshed out.

Comment: @MSalters: I think your last suggestion is a different, valid proposal. While they go well together, each of them can be considered independently.

Comment: @einpoklum: Not typing things is not the same thing as expressibility...I can't think of a single function that expresses its intent with explicit use of `std::nullopt` (or equivalent) that would be made clearer by omitting it. *Especially since everyone already knows that reaching the end of a returning function is already undefined behavior.* This would just be even more confusing.